# add css transition time to toggle class using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, transition

I want to add a transition time to my pure javascript toggle class function 
I knew how to code it but i forgot and now need some advice

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}
.class1 {
    color: #f00;
    background-color: #2fadac;
}

.class2 {
    color: #00f;
    background-color: #c33;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div" class="class1">click here</div>
<script>
function classToggle() {
    this.classList.toggle('class1');
    this.classList.toggle('class2');
    style.cssText ="-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;";
}
document.querySelector('#div').addEventListener('click', classToggle);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 8):

Try add the rule for transition in your target class itself.

```
.class1 {
    color: #f00;
    background-color: #2fadac;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.class2 {
    color: #00f;
    background-color: #c33;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Wa4c/)**

Or just apply the rule in a separate rule:

CSS:-

```
.class1 {
    color: #f00;
    background-color: #2fadac;
}

.class2 {
    color: #00f;
    background-color: #c33;
}
.transition{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div" class="class1 transition">click here</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/69Lh7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add transition on your CSS

```
#div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4L99u/)